# Как после добавления чисел в вектор вывести сумму первых (заданных пользователем) чисел

Tags: c++

Здравстуйте, как после функции while не прервать программу, а продолжить вводить данные. (отесть ввести y)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

 int main()
 {    
     cout << "enter some numbers \n";
     vector<int> v;
     int x;
     while (cin >> x)
         v.push_back(x);
     cout << "the sum of which first numbers would you like to display \n";
     int y;
     cin >> y;
     int res = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
         res += v[i];
     cout << "result " << res << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, вам нужен какой-то признак того, что вы ввели все числа в вектор. Например, все элементы вектора вводятся в первую строку, а число `y` во вторую. Или пусть ввод вектора кончается нулем, что-нибудь в этом роде. Также можно сначала запросить у пользователя количество чисел, а потом добавить их в вектор с помощью for'a

Comment: @EzikBro спасибо, через количество чисел я был сделал, но про 0 я что-то не подумал, спасибо )